# Multiple Silverlight Pages with one APX

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am currently looking into developing a silverlight app but I am having a couple of problems with it.

What I need is one APX file which can be embedded into any web page. The project to have multiple Silverlight Forms. At the moment I have a login form which correctly checks the username and password with a database and return true or false if they match. If it is true I want to display a second silverlight page.

E.g.

User loads www.mydomain.com/mysilverlightapp.htm

When the page loads it shows a login box called Login.cs.

If password exists MainScreen.cs is displayed within the same htm file.

Is this possible

Comment: How about a Silverlight Popup dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Navigation project template.  It will allow you to take multiple "pages" and navigate between them very easily.

http://stuff.seans.com/2010/05/07/silverlight-4-project-types-part-ii-%E2%80%93-silverlight-navigation-application/